# jQuery dialog and PHP grid

Tags: php, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have implemented jquery dialogbox within php grid but every time I open the same dialog box, it pulls the record into the box?

I declared the dialog box and used the following:

```
$("a.pop").each(function(i){

    $(this).click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
        $("#details").dialog('open');


    });

  });
```

any help is appreciated....

Answer (score 0):

Hope I am appreciated ... lol but please note that **code is not tested** so please let me know in case

```
$("a.pop").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
        $("#details").load($(this).attr('href')).dialog('open');    
    });
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the respond.  I actually solved it as follow:var rowId = $(this).attr('title'); //of clicked row
     $("#details_"+rowId).dialog('open');  Worked well.  Many thanks.